# checkbox can't create dynamically

Tags: android, android-checkbox

Can Anybody help me? checkbox can't create dynamically . Just like sometimes I use the program create 6 checkboxes. Sometimes I create 8 checkboxes. I want to set each checkbox a event to catch the time when it's checked.In the following way, I get an error:Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method.Change modifier of "i" to final.
The `mCheckTime` is a long array.

```
        for(int i=0;i<optionsNum;i++){
            mCheckBox[i]=new CheckBox(this);
            mCheckBox[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isCheck){
                    if (mCheckBox[i].isChecked()) {
                        mCheckTime[i] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Can't create means, what happened when you execute the above code..?

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly?

Comment: What do you do with `mCheckBox` after the code above?

Comment: Aside from your code not showing any attempt to add your CheckBoxes to any view, what is the following code supposed to do? `mCheckBox[i] = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: Sorry , i post wrong, it is mCheckTime[i] = System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 2):

if your content view is LinearLayout, try

```
final CheckBox mCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
    mCheckBox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isCheck) {
                    if (mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                        mCheckBox.setText(System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
                    }
                }
            });
    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    addContentView(mCheckBox, params);
```

**======EDIT======**

or try this

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(layout);
    CheckBox[] mCheckBox = new CheckBox[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        mCheckBox[i] = new CheckBox(this);
        mCheckBox[i].setText(i + "");
        mCheckBox[i]
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isCheck) {
                        if (isCheck) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    System.currentTimeMillis() + "",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        layout.addView(mCheckBox[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I use a final variable j to replace i inside the inner class.

```
for(int i=0;i<optionsNum;i++){
        final int j = i;
        mCheckBox[i]=new CheckBox(this);
        mCheckBox[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isCheck){
                if (mCheckBox[i].isChecked()) {
                    mCheckTime[i] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
        };
```